# Linux-headers and images in Ubuntu after installing vmware-tools

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, vmware-tools

Can I run a `dist-upgrade` for `linux-headers` and images in Ubuntu after installing `vmware-tools`? I ask this because I think `vmware-tools` also install something like a header and image which could be overridden if I upgrade my linux-headers.

Answer (score 0):

If `vmware-tools` overwrote a header file provided with `linux-headers`, the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers` will repair it.